# HP Fortify Audit Workbench v4 Generation of PDF Report

Tags: fortify

I have a .fpr report generated by HP Fortify scan. I am able to open it in Audit Workbench. Now, i want to generate a PDF report from this which list all the issues with the file names, source snippet and line numbers.

I have tried various options from Audit Workbench Report Generation, but don't seem to find the right combination for being able to do so.

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to generate all the issues into PDF and i think the same approach can be taken for other formats than pdf. The trick was to unchek the "Limit number of issues in each group"

Open Audit Workbench. Click Tools > Generate Legacy Report

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
ReportGenerator -format XML -f abcd.xml -source abcd.fpr
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.